# Join const char with int into a char*

Tags: c, char

Given this variables:

```
const char* Filename="file";
int size=100;
int num=300;
```

I want to put them together in one char* with this format "file_num_size" (file_300_100 in this case), so what in c++ would be as easy as do:

```
std::string newFile =Filename+std::to_string(size)+std::to_string(num);
```

How could I do it in C on the var `char* newFile;` ??

Thanks

--------------EDIT----------------

Thanks to all, I guess not setting a size to the var `newFile` would be a bit hard to achieve, so i will just go with sprintf and setting a size to newfile. THanks again.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat

Comment: Do you know the lengths in advance? Is truncation at a maximum length acceptable?

Comment: Use `sprintf()`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen the well, the point of this is that if the name of file exists, then to add `_i` at the end where `i` can go from 0 to....100k let's say

Comment: @Lomazo don't put "thanks etc." into the question but write it as a comment to the answer that you think is the best and click on the green outlines check mark.

Answer (score 4):

Roughly like this:

```
const char* Filename="file";
int size = 100;
int num = 300;
char newFile[50];    // buffer for 50 chars
sprintf(newfile, "%s_%d_%d", Filename, num, size);
```

You need to make sure that the filename is never longer than 49 chars.

If the length of filename can be very long this variant may be better:

```
const char* Filename="very_long_file_name_fooo_bar_evenlonger_abcde_blabla";
int size = 100;
int num = 300;
char *newFile = malloc(strlen(Filename) + 30);  // computing needed length
sprintf(newfile, "%s_%d_%d", Filename, num, size);
...
free(newFile);    // free the buffer, once you're done with it, but only then
```

The `+ 30` is a quick and dirty way to make room for the `_xxx_yyy`. There is room for improvement here.

Comment: or just use `snprintf()`?

Comment: Well, that's the point, i wanna make it for any kind of size for filename.

Comment: @Lomazo, you can always compute the length of the resulting string and allocate the appropriate space for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using c99 or higher version of C compiler they support variable length arrays, where we can allocate an auto array (on stack) of variable size.

Assuming that `size` and `num` are always the positive integers,  you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int getSize (int n) {
    int size = 1;
    while (n > 9) {
            n /= 10;
            size++;
    }
    return size;
}

int main()
{
    const char* Filename="file";
    int size = 100;
    int num = 300;

    int total_size = strlen(Filename)+getSize(size)+getSize(num)+1;

    char newFile[total_size]; //Variable length array

    sprintf(newFile, "%s_%d_%d", Filename, num, size);

    printf ("newfile : %s\n", newFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @martin: Initializing `size` with `1`. `while (n > 9)` because for number 1-9, the `getSize()` will return 1 otherwise `size` incremented based on digits in `n`. Do you foresee any problem with it?

Comment: There's no need for that function in the first place, since the integer constant is known at compile time. Simply do `#define SIZEOF_INT(i) (sizeof((char[]){#i})-1)` to determine how many digits the integer constant has. Example: `printf("%zu", SIZEOF_INT(300));`

Comment: @ H.S didn't see size is 1

Comment: @Hence "since the integer constant is known at compile time". The definition of an _integer constant_ (formal C term) is something like the raw number `100`. Sometimes these are also called "integer literals".

Answer (score 0):

In compile-time (fastest, but can't be changed):

```
#define FILE "file"
#define NUM 300
#define SIZE 100

#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define NEWFILE(file, num, size) file "_" STRINGIFY(num) "_" STRINGIFY(size)

...
const char* Filename = FILE;
int num = NUM;
int size = SIZE;
const char* newFile = NEWFILE(FILE, NUM, SIZE); // "file_300_100"
```

In run-time, slow but readable:

```
sprintf(str, "%s_%d_%d", file, num, size);
```

(Where `str` is large enough to contain the result - this has to be checked in advance)

Faster run-time versions do the integer to string conversion manually, then build the string manually step by step.